# error: The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'. DART

Tags: dart

How can I solve this?,I want to convert string expression to double but it gives error.

[image: How can I solve this?,I want to convert string expression to double but it gives error.]

```
    void addProduct() async {
    var result = await dbHelper.insert(Product(
        name: txtName.text,
        description: txtDescription.text,
        unitPrice: double.tryParse(txtUnitPrice.text)));
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @StephanVierkant IMO including the image here was a good choice since there was no additional info where the warning was being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of [`double.tryParse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/tryParse.html) is:

```dart
double? tryParse(String source)
```

`double?` indicates that the returned value might be `null`.

Now, the parameter `unitPrice` is of type `double` which cannot accept `null` as an input which `double.tryParse` might return.

---

- The simplest solution is to provide a fail-safe value by using `??` null-aware operator. Example:

```dart
    unitPrice: double.tryParse(txtUnitPrice.text) ?? 0.0));
```

- But judging from your code, there might be no default value that you can put and you'd want the code to fail in a safe manner instead. Then you can use `double.parse` method and simply handle the `FormatException` it throws when invalid input is received.

```dart
var result; 

try {
  result = await dbHelper.insert(Product(
      name: txtName.text,
      description: txtDescription.text,
      unitPrice: double.parse(txtUnitPrice.text)));
} on FormatException {
  // Do some action.
}
```

Further reading: [Why nullable types?](https://medium.com/dartlang/why-nullable-types-7dd93c28c87a)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Actually double.parse, not double.tryParse

Comment: `double.try` doesn't exist, most likely you meant `double.parse`

Comment: Yes, double.parse